# Redirection rule doesn't work in my .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I broke my head trying to find where the issue is:

I have the following redirection rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/productname(.*) https://website.com/category [R=301,NC,L]
```

but it doesn't work and I can't get why. Because this rule:

```
Redirect 301 ^/productname(.*) https://website.com/category/subcategory/productname
```

works fine.

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/productname(.*) https://website.com/category [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

That won't work in per-directory `.htaccess` files because the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is less the directory-prefix (the filesystem path of where the `.htaccess` file resides). The directory-prefix always ends in a slash, so the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* never starts with a slash.

From the [Apache docs for the `RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> In per-directory context (Directory and .htaccess), the Pattern is matched against only a partial path, for example a request of "/app1/index.html" may result in comparison against "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the RewriteRule is defined.
>
> The directory path where the rule is defined is stripped from the currently mapped filesystem path before comparison (up to and including a trailing slash). The net result of this per-directory prefix stripping is that rules in this context only match against the portion of the currently mapped filesystem path "below" where the rule is defined.

So, you would need to do remove the slash prefix, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^productname https://website.com/category [R=301,NC,L]
```

The trailing `(.*)` on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is superfluous in this example.

> ```
> Redirect 301 ^/productname(.*) https://website.com/category/subcategory/productname
> ```

This rule wouldn't "work fine". I think you mean `RedirectMatch`.

Note that `RewriteRule` and `Redirect` (and `RedirectMatch`) belong to different modules. mod_rewrite and mod_alias - you should avoid mixing redirects from both modules as you can get unexpected conflicts.